# Instagram API - What to do with emojis in data?

Tags: python, json, api, instagram

So I have been messing around with the Instagram API (client-side) and I run into a problem every time emojis are involved in the data.

My Code:

```
import requests
import json

response = requests.get("https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN")
status_code = response.status_code

if(status_code == 200):
    data = response.json()
```

Error Thrown:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'UCS-2' codec can't encode characters in position
>   135-135: Non-BMP character not supported in Tk

On my instagram account biography I have one emoji (the bear emoji). This error is thrown anytime it sees an emoji. If I remove the emoji and re-run there's no error.

The Bio data looks like this:

> "bio": "\ud83d\udc3b"

**Question:** What do I do so that the code either accepts emojis OR what can I do to completely remove emojis from the data?

Comment: Remove all surrogates. Or upgrade to a toolkit that supports full Unicode.

Comment: mind showing me how it's done kind sir :)

Comment: Are you using IDLE?